# Better way to compute this Lambert W function?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

I have an expression of this form:

$$W_0\left(\dfrac{\exp(\frac{a}{d})}{d \cdot \exp(\frac{b}{d})}\right)$$

However a lot of online implementations that use the Newton approximation will experience data type overflow since the process involves taking $e^{\text{big number}}$ since these are already exp terms.

Is there a way to simplify this in any way, shape, or form?

Comment: So $a>b$ and $d\ll (a-b)$?

Comment: Usually $a$ is the largest piece, sometimes $b$ and $d$ can be larger/smaller than each other (so I guess, technically, yes, to answer your question)

Comment: For example $a=496, b=30, d=13$ might be a sample representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should have a direct implementation of $l(x)=W(e^{x})$. I do not know of any such implementation so I guess, you should write it yourself. Just use your favorite solver (Newton or whatever) to solve the defining equation
$$ \ln y +y = x$$
with $l(x)=y$. A proper starting value is $y_0=x$.

Given an implementation of the function $l$, you obtain your result as
$$ l\left( \frac{a-b}{d} - \ln d\right).$$

Comment: Your $l(x)$ function is called the Wright $\omega(x)$ function and is defined as the unique solution of $\omega (x) + \ln \omega (x) = x.$

For real $x$ it can be written in terms of the Lambert $W$ function as $\omega(x) = W(e^x)$. See R.M. Corless, D.J. Jeffrey, On the Wright $\omega$ function,
http://www.orcca.on.ca/TechReports/2000/TR-00-12.html